# NameError after prompting player to enter a guess

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a word puzzle, but I got a NameError after I prompt the player to enter a guess.

My code:

```
.
.
.
print("The word is something like " + guess)
player_guess_letter= input("Guess a letter:")
```

After I enter a guess, say "f" in the error "NameError: name 'f' is not defined".

Comment: what version of Python are you using? I just tired your code in Python 3.7, and it works properly.

Comment: IDLE that runs Python 3, but the python launcher runs Python 2. Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Python 2, so instead of `input` use `raw_input` as follows:

```
player_guess_letter= raw_input("Guess a letter:")
```

In Python 2, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. Thus, it is trying to eval the value you entered. See more in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

In Python 3, you won't have this issue.